# MySQL Statement is not working in PHP but works perfectly fine in MySQL Workbench

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, syntax-error

If I try to execute it in the MySQL Workbench, it just works. However, it does not work when executet through the php script.  I am using MySQLi.
The php script throws this Error Message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM admins
> WHERE id = 2' at line 5

This is the Code from the php file:

```
function deleteAdmin($connection, $id_admin) {
  $sqlStmt = "UPDATE azubis 
              SET fk_ausbilder = 1 
              WHERE fk_ausbilder = $id_admin; 
              
              DELETE FROM admins 
              WHERE id = $id_admin";
              
  if (!$connection->query($sqlStmt)) {
    echo mysqli_error($connection);
  }
  closeConnection($connection);
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, `query` does not support multi-statement SQL queries. Do them separately.

Comment: Use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection